# LaravelShoppingCart and PNotify

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, pnotify

I am trying to use [LaravelShoppingCart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) with [PNotify](http://sciactive.com/pnotify/#demos-simple) and I am a little lost and could use some pointers.

This is the interface I have so far: [image]

When I click the yellow "add me" button, I spawn a new notification using PNotify on the top right, like you see in the picture.

What I want to do next is:

1. When I click the "add me" button, `Cart::add()` would be called, and my class would be added to the cart session
2. The yellow button turns to "remove me", which would be able to call `Cart::remove()`
3. The notification persists on the top right corner (even if you go to another page. It's essentially referencing `Cart::content()`), and when you click the "x" button on the notification, it would call `Cart::remove()` as well.

I'm not really looking for code (although if it helps with explanation, feel free). I just simply want someone to explain to me how I could achieve this.

It seems like I need to use AJAX. If so, what do I need to add to my Laravel project for it to use AJAX to add to cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily you need ajax. Every time you click "add me" button you just send a post request and add the class to your cart with Cart::add().
You display the added classes by listing the Cart::content(). Also you check in your view if the class is already added then change the button to remove class.

If you prefer ajax. then you just send a ajax call to your server with same process as mention. You don't have to add packages to your project to use ajax. you just need jquery plugin.

I prefer ajax because you don't have to load your page but it needs a lot of work.

**Update**

you need something like this.

```
$('#button').click(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'url',
  data: {your: data},
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){
 //do something with your data
});

return false;

});
```

**Note**

In your ajax function. It should look like this if you submit the form.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{!! route('route') !!}",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'html'
 }).done(function (data) {
```

but if your just passing selected data you need to pass the _token.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{!! route('route') !!}",
    data: {data: value, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    dataType: 'html'
 }).done(function (data) {
```

**Update**

Here is my sample code of my back-end.

```
public function addItem(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'field' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $data = Cart::content();
            return view('errorview', compact('data'))->withErrors($validator);
        }

        Cart::add($data['id'], $data['name'], $data['qty'],
            $data['amount']);

        $data = Cart::content();

        return view('myview', compact('data'));
    }
```

**Update**

You need to add a class in all your buttons. something like this.

```
 $('.btn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "{!! route('route') !!}",
                    data: {id: $(this).prop('id').substr(9), _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                    dataType: "html"
                }).done(function (data) {
                   //more code here
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Am I POSTing to another route which receives inputs? That's primarily the part I am confused about. I've used AJAX very little, so I am confused on when I should use it.

Comment: yes you need to create another route to receive the inputs.

Comment: God I just realized I could POST it. Although that would trigger a page refresh. The example you gave me, would that trigger a refresh? Also, what type of changes would I need to make in my back-end to accept the AJAX requests?

Comment: Oh. i forgot. You need to add return false before the closing tag.

Comment: Your regular post route can be used. You don't have to add anything.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the new route will be accepting inputs, and inside will be the `Cart::add()`, `Cart::remove()` etc right?

Comment: Hey dakine. Thanks for the answers. I know how to POST using AJAX :P. I'm just not sure how add to cart using AJAX using the LaravelShoppingCart library, i.e. how do I asynchronously add items to cart using AJAX?

Comment: Your CSRF token reminder is a god send! I was able to make an AJAX request to a new route I defined. Thank you so much dakine!!

Comment: I've attributed individual IDs to the buttons, so if I have 10 classes, the button ID will go from button1 to button10. How do I change my jQuery code to reflect those ID changes? $('#button') obviously doesn't work.